# Change RecyclerView data when it's empty

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to make a first query and display the data in the RecyclerView

But, if there is no data, I want to display an other RecyclerView with Suggestions for the User

I already know how to make a Recyclerview with Empty TextView, but here instead of the Empty TextView, I need a new RecyclerView with different Query and Data
(I use Firestore for my Database)

Is it possible ? :-)

Comment: Yes, `RecyclerView` can handle many different types of items at the same time. You can use that same `RecyclerView` for both cases, just change elements inside.

Comment: you can set data to adapter based on the data

Answer (score -1):

Just check if you have data

```
db.collection("users")
    .add(user)
    .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        if(result != null){
               for (item in result) {
                    var obj: JSONObject = JSONObject(document?.data)
                    array?.put(obj)
                }
              adapter.setData(array)
              //make recyclerview visible
           }else {
            //   fire new query, 
            //   hide recyclerview
           }          
    }
    .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                     //   fire new query, 
            //   hide recyclerview
    }
```

You can use the same recycler view to show different data, if you want to keep things separate, make different adapters.